# npm install gives same node-gyp problem on Mac and Ubuntu

Tags: npm, npm-install, cardano

I am trying to npm install this repo: https://github.com/Berry-Pool/nami-wallet
I tried on two different machines but the result is the same.
I tried many different solution found for similar problems one of which to nvm use a different node version, but the problem persists.

Can anyone address me to where to look or ask help to find a solution as I am out of ammunition on how to find one.

here is the log https://pastebin.pl/view/17433dd0

```
12021 verbose stack Error: command failed
12021 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/userx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
12021 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
12021 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
12021 verbose stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
12021 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
12021 verbose stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
12022 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.14.1
12023 verbose cwd /home/userx/git/nami-wallet
12024 verbose Linux 5.13.0-27-generic
12025 verbose argv "/home/userx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node" "/home/userx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/npm" "install" "--force"
12026 verbose node v16.13.2
12027 verbose npm  v8.3.2
12028 error code 1
12029 error path /home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-sass
12030 error command failed
12031 error command sh -c node scripts/build.js
12032 error Building: /home/userx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node /home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
12032 error make: Entering directory '/home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-sass/build'
...
g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/src -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/zlib -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/subset_map.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/subset_map.o ../src/libsass/src/subset_map.cpp
12032 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/src -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/zlib -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_c.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_c.o ../src/libsass/src/to_c.cpp
12032 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/src -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/zlib -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_value.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_value.o ../src/libsass/src/to_value.cpp
12032 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/src -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/zlib -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/units.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/units.o ../src/libsass/src/units.cpp
12032 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/src -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/zlib -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/utf8_string.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/utf8_string.o ../src/libsass/src/utf8_string.cpp
12032 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/src -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/zlib -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/util.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/util.o ../src/libsass/src/util.cpp
12032 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/src -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/zlib -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/values.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/values.o ../src/libsass/src/values.cpp
12032 error   rm -f Release/obj.target/src/sass.a && ar crs Release/obj.target/src/sass.a Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o 
12032 error   rm -rf "Release/sass.a" && cp -af "Release/obj.target/src/sass.a" "Release/sass.a"
12032 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/src -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/config -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/uv/include -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/zlib -I/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o ../src/binding.cpp
12032 error make: Leaving directory '/home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-sass/build'
12033 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
12033 error gyp verb cli [
12033 error gyp verb cli   '/home/userx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node',
12033 error gyp verb cli   '/home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
12033 error gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
12033 error gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
12033 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
12033 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
12033 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
12033 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
12033 error gyp verb cli ]
12033 error gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
12033 error gyp info using node@16.13.2 | linux | x64
12033 error gyp verb command rebuild []
12033 error gyp verb command clean []
12033 error gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
12033 error gyp verb command configure []
12033 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
12033 error gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
12033 error gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.18
12033 error gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
12033 error gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.13.2
12033 error gyp verb command install [ '16.13.2' ]
12033 error gyp verb install input version string "16.13.2"
12033 error gyp verb install installing version: 16.13.2
12033 error gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
12033 error gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
12033 error gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
12033 error gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
12033 error gyp verb install version is good
12033 error gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.13.2
12033 error gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-sass/build
12033 error gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-sass/build
12033 error gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
12033 error gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
12033 error (node:116619) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
12033 error (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
12033 error gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
12033 error gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
12033 error gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
12033 error gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
12033 error gyp info spawn args [
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '/home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '-f',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   'make',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '/home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '/home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node/common.gypi',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-gyp',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-sass',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   'build',
12033 error gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
12033 error gyp info spawn args ]
12033 error gyp verb command build []
12033 error gyp verb build type Release
12033 error gyp verb architecture x64
12033 error gyp verb node dev dir /home/userx/.node-gyp/16.13.2
12033 error gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
12033 error gyp info spawn make
12033 error gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
...
12033 error gyp ERR! build error 
12033 error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
12033 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
12033 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
12033 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
12033 error gyp ERR! System Linux 5.13.0-27-generic
12033 error gyp ERR! command "/home/userx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node" "/home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
12033 error gyp ERR! cwd /home/userx/git/nami-wallet/node_modules/node-sass
12033 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
12033 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
12033 error gyp ERR! not ok
```